# How do I get by attribute value with xpath in node js

Tags: node.js, xml, xpath, attributes

Given XML

```
<ValCredLookup>
  <ValCredName name="val-cred-api-cust">
    <certificate thumbprint="12345">
        <clientID id="1bbfea">
            <Merchant-id>123456789</Merchant-id>
        </clientID>            
    </certificate>        
  </ValCredName>
</ValCredLookup>
```

How do I use xpath to get certificate or clientID by attribute value? I have tried things like

```
doc = new xmldom().parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');
var xpath = require('xpath');
var valcredname = xpath.select("/ValCredLookup/ValCredName/@name='valcred-api-cust'", doc);
```

which works, but if I try

```
var valcredname = xpath.select("/ValCredLookup/ValCredName/@name='val-cred-api-cust'/certificate", doc);
```

This doesn't work.

Also how do I reference variables in the xpath

```
var vcname = 'valcred-api-cust';
var nodes = xpath.select("/ValCredLookup/ValCredName/@name=????, doc);
```

What I really need to do is get elements under clientID with an xpath which uses attributes name, thumbprint and id, which are all variables. Like this

```
var vc = 'val-cred-api-cust';
var tp = '12345';
var id = 1bbfea';
var nodes = xpath.select("/ValCredLookup/ValCredName/@name=vc/certificate/@thumbprint=tp/clientID/@id=id, doc);
```

Ok figured out the variable bit

```
var vc = "'val-cred-api-cust'";
```

just needed the single quotes in the string, but as far as an xpath statement with multiple attribute values is concerned I don't think that node js xpath can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct expression to filter `ValCredName` by `name` attribute value, and then return the corresponding `certificate` element would be :

```
/ValCredLookup/ValCredName[@name='val-cred-api-cust']/certificate
```

I don't know if the library that you use provide a better way to access JS variable in XPath. If it doesn't, then you can concatenate JS variable values to construct the XPath expression, for example :

```
var vc = "val-cred-api-cust";
var query = "/ValCredLookup/ValCredName[@name='" + vc + "']/certificate";
var valcredname = xpath.select(query, doc);
```

Comment: Thanks @har07 . That should have been obvious but sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees.